# React Table - access state values inside Cell functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, state, react-table

I have multiple React-Table columns using the Cell functions :

In the main class :

```
Cell: function (props) {
  return (
    <span>
      <ChildClass
        id={props.original._id} myemail={this.state.email}
      />
    </span>
  );
},
```

So I get the error : **TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined**

I want to use the state inside that Cell function.

Thank you

Comment: you cannot ue `this.state` in functional component.

Comment: you can use `useState` hook inside the functional component to manage state. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: any example on my case ?

Comment: can you post the whole code of the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not getting **"this"**, You have to make this a lambda(arrow) function or need to bind the this.

```
Cell:(props) => {
  return (
    <span>
      <ChildClass
        id={props.original._id} myemail={this.state.email}
      />
    </span>
  );
},
```

I hope this will work for you, or otherwise share more details of the code.

Comment: Solved ! can you please explain to me why ?

Comment: Actually, while you are using the es5, in that case, we have to explicitly define the "this", in which context the function will going to call by using bind, otherwise, it will take the this of the context where we define the function. but when we use es6  arrow function, it automatically  binds the "this" with the function where we call it, as it don't have its own context